# Oracle : select words which start by character or associated special character

Tags: java, sql, oracle, select

I'm not very at ease with Oracle. My project uses Java 8, Springboot, JpaRepository and an Oracle DB. I've this query in my repository :

```
@Query("SELECT lex FROM Lexique lex WHERE UPPER(lex.titre) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT(:lettre,'%')) order by lex.titre ASC ")
List<Lexique> findAllWordsStartingBy(@Param("lettre") String lettre);
```

When I have the "E" letter, I well retrieve words which start with E. But it's a french project and I also need to retrieve words that start with "é" or "è". 
And this for all letters which can be associated to special characters.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Java uses unicode, and unicode considers all those letters as separate code points.

Comment: Seems like a known issue with Oracle, perhaps the following link can help:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2470289?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Modify nls_sort, and nls_comp

```
  alter session set nls_sort=french_m_ai;    --(_m -> multilingual , _ai -> accent insensitive and case insensitive )
  alter session set nls_comp=linguistic; -- comparisions base on linguistic rule
```

Now your query is accent insensitive and case insensitive

```
SELECT lex FROM Lexique lex WHERE lex.titre LIKE :lettre||'%'
```

But changing these param will affect others queries.

2)  Use `nlssort` .Nlssort is returning RAW type and it's not possible to use it with like clause but you can do this workaround.

```
@Query("SELECT lex FROM Lexique lex WHERE nlssort(substr(lex.titre,1,1), 'NLS_SORT=FRENCH_M_AI') =  nlssort(:letter, 'NLS_SORT=FRENCH_M_AI') ",  nativeQuery = true)
```

But I'm not sure about the second solution